# JQuery Loop Through all File Input Fields to Get Size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to loop through all file input fields and set an error message if any are over 5MB as a first step to form validation.

I'm using a click event on the submit button. The problem is that "key" is not defined.

This form can have up to 10 file input fields, added via AJAX called `images[]`

```
        /* loop through all file inputs to check size */
        $("#my-form").find("input[type='file']").each(function(key, value) {
            var el = this.files[key];
            if(el.size > 5242880 || el.fileSize > 5242880) {
                errorMessage = 'Files must be less than 5MB.';
            }
        });
```

If I use `this.files[0]` I can get the first field's size, but having trouble looping through all elements. Appreciate your input or other solutions. Thanks much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this

```
$("#my-form").find("input[type=file]").each(function(index, field){
   const file = field.files[0];
   if(file.size > 5242880 || file.fileSize > 5242880) {
      errorMessage = 'Files must be less than 5MB.';
   }
});
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kmm67nLz/

For file inputs with multiple attribute

```
$("#my-form").find("input[type=file]").each(function(index, field){
  for(var i=0;i<field.files.length;i++) {
    const file = field.files[i];
    if(file.size > 5242880 || file.fileSize > 5242880) {
      errorMessage = 'Files must be less than 5MB.';
      alert(errorMessage);
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kmm67nLz/1/

The second one is perfect to use in any of single or multiple file input.

Comment: I don't have an problem getting the first key [0], it's the ones after. Your fiddle only works on the first one.

Comment: I've just checked it works for 2 files in 2 separate inputs. May be I don't understand what exactly you're asking for. Is it about multiple file input?

Comment: Leave the first one blank and only add a file to your 2nd input.

Comment: That goes to error handling, just skip it or do whatever you want if you find the variable `file` undefined.

Comment: I see you added a for loop to your fiddle. Let me update my code tomorrow and I think this will work.